# how to set lookup-method programatically in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am creating spring bean at runtime and I want to hookup lookup-method property in it, please help me out how it can be achieved.

**Edit 1:** Below is the helper class

```
public class CommonHelper implements MethodReplacer{



@Override
public Object reimplement(Object arg0, Method arg1, Object[] arg2)
        throws Throwable {
    //replaced logic
    return null;
}
```

and it is configured as bean in `spring.xml`

Now, Below I am creating bean at runtime and also, I have injected one property which I am able to retrieve, So, how can I set "replaced-method" for this particular bean?

reference link http://java.dzone.com/articles/method-injection-spring

```
GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
    beanDefinition.setBeanClass(TestClass.class);
    beanDefinition.setLazyInit(false);
    beanDefinition.setAbstract(false);
    beanDefinition.setAutowireCandidate(true);

    beanDefinition.setPropertyValues(new MutablePropertyValues().add("str", "getyest"));

    registry.registerBeanDefinition("dynamicBean", beanDefinition);

    Object bean = appContext.getBean("dynamicBean");
```

Comment: Show us what you have done?

Comment: edited question, please check.

Comment: Dis you tried as mentioned in post, creating <lookup-method name="reimplement" bean="commonhelper " /> in your spring.xml and accessing it in class containing GenericBeanDefinition code?

Comment: yes, I tried and it is working fine.But I want to create bean at runtime and set the lookup-method property.